# Merging multiple XML files

Tags: python, xml, merge, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a directory of xml files and I'm trying to merge them all into one big xml file

```
full = ET.Element('dataset')
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):
    tree = ET.parse(filename, parser=xmlp)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for pair in root: #root.iter('pair'):
        full.append(pair)
```

I tried the above code and get this trivial error:

> ParseError: parsing finished: line 330, column 0

The problem is that only the first file is appended to the new xml doc, how can I avoid this? Or is there a better way of merging? (The structures are identical)

Edit: they are of this structure:

```
<dataset>
<pair>
<t1></t1>
<t2></t2>
</pair>
...
</dataset>
```

Update: Used XML Copy Editor, and couldn't open told me unknown encoding MS932 even though it is in ISO-8859-1. Same error I got from trying to open with lxml and not xml in python. Manually recreated a new xml, not really a solution but oh well.

Thanks

Comment: Your code worked for me with my simple xml files.  I think your xml files may be malformed.

Comment: maybe they are generally valid but somewhere there is an error? I added the structure so you can see. in any case is there a workaround?

Comment: Your example structure looks fine.  How about verifying that the xml files are valid by using `xmllint`?  e.g. `xmllint --noout *.xml`.  If all of them are fine, then no output will be printed.  Or you could print out the files you are parsing one at a time to find out which one is causing the problem.  It's hard to say what kind of workaround is possible without knowing how bad the xml parsing error is.

Comment: i dont have xmllint but i validated the first two files through (the parse error appears after parsing through the first) https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and no errors were found

Comment: why do i think i am getting the error because it is done iterating through all the pairs (of the first) and then for whatever reason doesn't continue onto the second file

Comment: We need to see content with structure as encoding occurs with text values. Is there non-English text known to have special chars/accents? Any encoding header lines, namespaces, etc.? Please post fuller sample. And use online XML validators to help.